# std::vector<> datatype python wrapper in ctypes

Tags: c++, python-3.x, ctypes

How to write python wrapper for vector datatype in ctypes library? I couldn't find any reference in ctypes documentation. Below is my case i need to write python wrapper,

**header file**

```
struct ClassItem {
    int rollNumber = 0;
    float score = 0;
};

struct ClassData {
    std::vector<ClassItem> v_classItem;
};

//API
int show_class(ClassData *p_class_data, uint8_t max_number);
```

**python wrapper**

```
class ClassData (Structure):
_fiels_ = [
(v_classItem , ??) #datatype declaration
]
```

Comment: Do yopu need *v\_classItem* to be a *std::vector<ClassItem>*? Or could it be a pointer?

Comment: @CristiFati, I will prefer _v_classItem_ to be in vector. if not then will try pointer.
Will be useful if i get both the implementation, i can do actual code implementation and check.

Comment: If you need vectors and the inner objects accessible from *Python*, then maybe *CTypes* isn't the best choice. You could try *PyBind11*. There are ways to get past this, but they're just workarounds.

Comment: @CristiFati, Currently all my wrapper is in ctypes, if i try pybind11 only for this API. will it be work with ctypes wrapper? And as you said anyway to implement it with pointer?
Because i'm not accessing any inner objects of vectors in python. I just have to pass this _vector_ structure as parameter in _showclass_ API mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with `pointer` for `vector` in ctypes and it worked for me. I can able to access both the variables in `ClassItem` structure.

**Python Datatypes**

```
class ClassItem {
    ('rollNumber', ctdt.c_int),
    ('score', ctdt.c_float)
};

class ClassData (Structure):
_fiels_ = [
(v_classItem , ctdt.POINTER(ClassItem)) #datatype declaration
]
```

**Accessing data**

```
data_obj = ClassData()
print('****************')
print('RECEIVED DATA')
for i in range(0,5): # Since it is a pointer, range should be known and hardcoded
    print('[PYTHON APP]INDEX:', data_obj.v_classItem[i].rollNumber, \
        'SCORE:', data_obj.v_classItem[i].score)
print('****************')
```